# Tweepy: bad Authentication Data

Tags: python, tweepy

I've been trying to do some basic sentiment analysis on some tweets about La Sagrada Familia, and cannot for the life of me figure out why I get this basd authentication data error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "saDemo.py", line 15, in <module>
    public_tweets = api.search('')
  File "/Users/declancasey/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 252, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/Users/declancasey/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 234, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 215, 'message': 'Bad Authentication data.'}]
```

I've seen other people have issues where it relates to the keys they're using, but I gave the original keys I used a few days in case it hadn't yet authenticated, but still get the same error. I've regenerated my keys several times over the past few days, messed with the formatting, tried commenting out different lines but keep getting this error. I'm using python 3.8 and am on Mac Big Sur, any help would be appreciated. My code is below:

```
import tweepy
from textblob import TextBlob

consumer_key = "XXXX"
consumer_secret = "XXXX"
access_token = "XXXX"
access_token_secret = "XXXX"
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.search("La Sagrada Familia")

for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
    analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
    print(analysis.sentiment)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used your code and could not reproduce the error:
**Python 3.7.4**
I suggest you check your API keys by loggin into your Twitter developer account or try using a different key.

```
import tweepy
from textblob import TextBlob

consumer_key = key[0]
consumer_secret = key[1]
access_token = key[2]
access_token_secret = key[3]
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
public_tweets = api.search("La Sagrada Familia")
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
    analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
    print(analysis.sentiment)
```

**This is the output I got:** (I've removed the URLs from output)

```
El Evangelio del dia 27 DE DICIEMBRE – DOMINGO -La Sagrada Familia:  Jesús, María y José –  Ciclo B  SAN JUAN  EVAN… 
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
Lecturas LSE: La Sagrada Familia (B), 27 de diciembre de 2020  a través de @YouTube
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
LAUDES 2020/12/27 #LaudesFrayNelson para la Fiesta de la Sagrada Familia
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
LECTIO 2020/12/27 LECTURA ESPIRITUAL. #LectioFrayNelson para la Fiesta de la Sagrada Familia
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
RT @DespertaFerro11: Els que estigueu demà prop de la Sagrada Família, passeu a donar suport a @JuntsXCat! Es necessita el teu aval! #Junts…
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
RT @HdadBorriquita:  ACTUALIDAD | La imagen de San Juan Evangelista se encuentra en el Altar Mayor de la Parroquia de San Agustín con moti…
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
RT @alvpe: Basílica de la Sagrada Família, Barcelona. 
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
RT @DespertaFerro11: Els que estigueu demà prop de la Sagrada Família, passeu a donar suport a @JuntsXCat! Es necessita el teu aval! #Junts…
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
RT @DespertaFerro11: Els que estigueu demà prop de la Sagrada Família, passeu a donar suport a @JuntsXCat! Es necessita el teu aval! #Junts…
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
RT @bsainzm: hasta que una mujer alzó la mano. El padre agradeció a la mujer y pidió a la familia de migrantes que pasara al frente. La "fa…
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
RT @DespertaFerro11: Els que estigueu demà prop de la Sagrada Família, passeu a donar suport a @JuntsXCat! Es necessita el teu aval! #Junts…
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
RT @SemiCuenca: El Oratorio y la Capilla del Seminario se “visten” de Navidad. Sagrada Familia, sed guía y estímulo para padres e hijos. Qu…
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
RT @DespertaFerro11: Els que estigueu demà prop de la Sagrada Família, passeu a donar suport a @JuntsXCat! Es necessita el teu aval! #Junts…
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
La sagrada familia de Nazaret, la de Jesús, era a ojos de su tiempo una familia desestructurada: un hijo inesperado… 
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
RT @DespertaFerro11: Els que estigueu demà prop de la Sagrada Família, passeu a donar suport a @JuntsXCat! Es necessita el teu aval! #Junts…
Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)
```

Comment: I appreciate it, I've tried though, even regenerated them a few different times